# What is the updating chart pattern with queue()?

Tags: json, d3.js, csv

I think most people on this forum know the enter(), update(), exit() pattern in the reusable chart [examples from Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

My question is, how can you use [queue()](https://github.com/mbostock/queue), which preloads data, with this pattern?

Because the essence of the e,p,e pattern is to callback the data function from within a closure and queue is by definition called once, then calls separate functions, is there a way to use it with updating charts?

**Update:** I would like to pass in the queued datafile as a function parameter, then access that object for my updates.

My initial code looks like:

```
rateById = d3.map(); 

queue() 
.defer(d3.csv, "./data/femaleChloropleth.csv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.endneighborhood, d.rides); }) 
.await(ready); 

function ready(error, femaleChloropleth) { 

console.log(femaleChloropleth);
```

But console.log() is returning an empty array and i know d3 is accessing the csv file. If I remove the mapping function, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend considering the use of `queue()` just as you would the use of `d3.json()`.  You use the results of queue (generally several json objects) to feed into any d3 enter / update / exit paradigm you wish.

Comment: how do you feed them in as you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue()` library can be thought of as a way to make multiple data calls at once, then call a function on the results when that data is loaded.  It is very similar to `d3.xhr` functions like `d3.json` in this way:

To load a single file of external data, you might use the following:

```
d3.json("path/to/file.json", ready)

function ready(error, jsonData) {
  var selection = d3.selectAll(".something")
      .data(jsonData);
  selection.enter().append("something").attr(etc..);
  selection.attr(etc..);
  selection.exit.remove();
});
```

If you wanted to load multiple files and use this data together, you'd have to nest these, i.e., `d3.json` calls, and wait for each file to load in order.  Instead, `queue()` allows us to do the same thing, but loads multiple files concurrently:

```
queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "path/to/file.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "path/to/file.csv")
  .defer(d3.tsv, "path/to/file.txt")
  .await(ready);

function ready(error, jsonData, csvData, tsvData) {
  //now you can use all three data sets in your general update paradigm
  //and did not have to wait for all three to load sequentially
}
```

Comment: OK that is what I thought. I am not returning the csv array when using console.log in this scenario:

var rateById = d3.map();
queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, "./data/femaleChloropleth.csv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.endneighborhood, d.rides); })
  .await(ready);


function ready(error, femaleChloropleth) {
 
  console.log(femaleChloropleth);

Comment: If you are only loading one dataset, i.e.: "./data/femaleChloropleth.csv", you do not need `queue()`, just use d3.json as per the above example

Comment: Fair enough. Is that causing my parameter loss problem, do you think?

Comment: probably not, perhaps you could put an example of the error up on jsfiddle, or something similar?  Try putting something like this in the first line of the `ready` function: `if (error) console.error(error);`  Then check the console after running.

Comment: if (error) console.error(error) does not return in the console.

Comment: It is difficult to troubleshoot further without seeing a working example of the error

Comment: There's no error. If you look at the above code, you'll see my attempt. I just want to log the object after passing it to the function as a paraemter.