# Why is the histogram not displaying if I read the data from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I wanted to reproduce a histogram based on this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450 but read the input data from a sql table.
To read the data to "values" works, but only if I put an alert after I read it from SQL the bars are showing up in the browser.

I assume the svg is rendered before all the data is read?

```
var values = [];
var counter = 0;

d3.json("php/data2.php", function(error, arrw) {
    arrw.forEach(function(d) {
        values.push(parseFloat(arrw[counter]["close"]));
        counter++;
    });
}); 

alert(); // without this alert the bars are not displayed in the svg
```

Comment: Does data2.php return the data in the right format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the D3 library `queue()` to time your updates.

So something like:

```
queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "php/data2.php")
  .await(ready);

function ready(error, arrw) {
  //now you can use the data set in your general update paradigm
  //and did not have to wait the data to load sequentially

 arrw.forEach(function(d) {
        values.push(parseFloat(arrw[counter]["close"]));
        counter++;
});
}
```

[More about queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695507/what-is-the-updating-chart-pattern-with-queue)

[More about D3 and mySQL.](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html)

Comment: I did not have to use the queue in the end but rather put all the svg variables into a function and called that function after I filled the values array.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Nice going.

Answer (score 1):

how about run this script after all doms loaded(`$(document).ready()`), have a try  and good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i am not sure how to integrate the snippet into my code. Should I create a function "loaded" and put the d3.json part inside?

Comment: ...It's just a js event. create a function(e.g getData) and put your codes above in it.  then：  $(document).ready(getData());

Comment: Queue is a d3 library that provides this function, without needing jquery.